# G++ -I option for compiling program

Tags: g++, compilation

Here is a little problem that cannot be resolved by me such a Linux program newbie.

Now I have a main.cpp program which need to be compiled, there is a

```
#include "Down.h"
```

in the front of file.

Actually, this header file exist in the other directory, which locates at 
`../../../include` 
directory. Besides, some other header files needed by Down.h also locate at this ../../../include directory.

Here is the problem, I compile main.cpp with command

```
g++ -I /../../../include main.cpp
```

However, it gives lots of error info which means it is not correct to be done like this.

Should I also change the include declaration into this one?

```
#include "../../../include/DownConvert.h"
```

May you please leave me with some advice? Thanks.

### Edit:

After using `g++ -I ../../../include main.cpp`, I get the following errors:

```
$ g++ -I ../../../include main.cpp 

In file included from ../../../include/DownConvert.h:98,
from main.cpp:92: ../../../include/ResizeParameters.h:4:22: error:
TypeDefs.h: No such file or directory 

In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algo.h:61, 
from /usr/include/c++/4.4/algorithm:62, 
from ../../../include/H2
```

Comment: you've used both "Down.h" and "DownConvert.h" in your sample code, which is correct?

Comment: after using g++ -I../../../include main.cpp, 
I get the following errors, maybe you can take a look at them, thanks.

jl@jl-linux:~/videocoding/jsvm2/JSVM/H264Extension/src/tools/PSNR$ g++ -I ../../../include main.cpp
In file included from ../../../include/DownConvert.h:98,
                 from main.cpp:92:
../../../include/ResizeParameters.h:4:22: error: TypeDefs.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algo.h:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.4/algorithm:62,
                 from ../../../include/H2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
g++ -I /../../../include main.cpp
```

See that leading slash after the `-I`? That's an absolute path.
Change it to a relative path (shown below) and it'll work OK.

```
g++ -I ../../../include main.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

g++ -I ../../../include main.cpp

ought to work

Answer (score 0):

Try to use -v option:

```
g++ -v -I ../../../include main.cpp
```

And check that list of directories to search for include files contains your folder and there is no complains that this folder is absent. If there is this sort of complains correct the path that you give after -I