# podofo.h - No such file or directory

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake, podofo

I built podofo-0.9.2 using the standard cmake and make install procedure. I have include files in the /usr/include/podofo directory. I added it to my path. Then I tried to compile the podofotxtextract example by using the following syntax.

```
cd podofo/tools/podofotxtextract
g++ -c -Wall TextExtractor.cpp TextExtractor.h podofotxtextract.cpp -lpodofo -lfreetype
-lfontconfig -ljpeg -lz
```

But for some reason the compilation fails saying :

```
podofo.h - no such file or directory
```

This is the value of my path

```
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/include/podofo
```

Maybe I'm missing something. I have linked the libraries. I have even included it in the path. What am I missing?

Comment: How did you include the header? `#include <podofo.h>` or `#include "podofo.h"`?

Comment: #include<podofo.h> (I know #include"podofo.h" is the same directory/same project header)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you miss the `-I` to set the include path. It's a compilation error, not a linker one.

```
-I/path/to/dir/of/podofo
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to somehow get around this error? Can't I add this to some file? (I added the directory to $PATH : the include file resides in /usr/include/podofo, but somehow it is unable to find it there). Thanks again.

Comment: The `$PATH` is not expected to handle includes, please refer to [GCC Environment Variables Reference](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html) for further details. As your dependency, you can use CMake (and the `include_directories` + `find_package`) to automate this.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `I` option to add your `podofo.h` 'findable' by the `g++` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1803467/g-i-option-for-compiling-program), may help).

`g++ -c -Wall -I/my/path/to/podofo/h TextExtractor.cpp TextExtractor.h podofotxtextract.cpp -lpodofo -lfreetype
-lfontconfig -ljpeg -lz`